# if $p \not= 2$ and $a^2 \equiv -1 \text{(mod p) }$ then $p \equiv 1 \text{(mod 4)}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $p$ be a prime number which is not equal to 2. Prove that if there exists an integer $a$ such that $a^2 \equiv -1 \text{(mod p) }$ then $p \equiv 1 \text{(mod 4)}$.

My attempt:
let $p$ be a prime number not equal to 2. Suppose $p \not \equiv 1 \text{(mod 4)}$. Since $p \not= 2$, p must be odd, therefore $p \equiv 3 \text{(mod 4)}$

We have that $a^2 \equiv -1 \text{(mod p) }$ so $p| a^2 + 1 \implies  a^2 + 1 = pm$ for some integer $n$.

$a^2 \equiv 0 \text{(mod 4)} \text{ or } a^2 \equiv 1 \text{(mod 4)} \implies a^2 + 1 \equiv 1 \text{(mod 4)} \text{ or } a^2 + 1 \equiv 2 \text{(mod 4)}$. This means that

$a^2 + 1 \equiv pm \equiv 3m \equiv 1 \text{(mod 4)}$ or

$a^2 + 1 \equiv pn \equiv 3n \equiv 2 \text{(mod 4)}$

But I am not able to reach any contradiction. What am I missing here?

Comment: Raise $a^2\equiv-1$ to the $\frac12(p-1)$-th power.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $p=4n+3$.  If $a^2\equiv -1$ for some nonzero residue $a$, then $a^{(4n+2)}=(a^2)^{(2n-1)}\equiv (-1)^{(2n-1)}\equiv -1$.  But Fermat's Little Theorem renders a different residue for $a^{(4n+2)}$, can you see that?

Comment: We have not talked about residues in the course I am taking, can you explain it without that?

Comment: you should be able to understand the term residue if you understand modular arithmetic

Comment: And Fermat's Little Theorem.